# Higher resolution laptop compared to second monitor

Tags: windows, laptop, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1

I have a Yoga 2 Pro (13.3") that has a resolution capacity of 3200x1800. I've been wondering about getting a budget 27" monitor. These, of course, come in 1920x1080.

I'm developing on it rather than gaming but after reading several different forums I'm still a little worried about the resolution (and ppi) in relation to the size. Is this a legitimate concern at all or am I reading the criticisms from people that just can't live without 4K resolutions?

I don't expect 3200x1800 on the second monitor, but is it possible to push it past 1920x1080 to meet in the middle?

Comment: What's your question? ppi difference is completely subjective, so we can't answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't expect 3200x1800 on the second monitor,
>   but is it possible to push it past 1920x1080 to meet in the middle?

Yes and no.

The monitor will have 1920x1080 pixels (or sets of sub-pixels) available. There is not way to change that without buying another screen.

However you can use a higher resolution. It will just be scaled down to match the display.

---

Example 1:

(The other way around (to a lower resolution since that is easier to explain).

Say I have a 800x600 screen (or 8x6 as shown) with a line on it.

On a 8x6 screen it would look as the ASCII picture on the left.
On a 4x3 screen it would look as the ASCII picture on the right.

```
     (8x6)         (4x3 on 8x6)
    o. .. .. ..     oo .. .. ..
    .o .. .. ..     oo .. .. ..

    .. o. .. ..     .. oo .. ..
    .. .. .. ..     .. oo .. ..

    .. .. .. ..     .. .. oo ..
    .. .. .. ..     .. .. oo ..
```

Notice that the right side picture is much coarser.

---

For upscaling something similar needs to be done.

E.g. If I configure 1600x1200 on a 1200x1200 display then I will need to drop one in every four pixels in order to make it fit. **this will make the picture fuzzy**

```
  1234567889ABCDEF ->  123 567 89A CDE 
                          ^   ^   ^   ^
                          |   |   |   |
                    These four will not be drawn 
                    since we do not have the pixels
                    to draw them on.
```

The result of these kind of shenigans is usually a fuzzy, hard to read display.

Therefor I recommend using the native resolution of a flatpanel monitor or a multiple of it.

For 1920x1080 *probably* displays a crisp:

- 1920x1200
- 960x600
- 3840x2400

There is no clean match with 3200x1800 in above list.

> or am I reading the criticisms from people that just can't live without 4K resolutions?

I am one of those people who rarely has enough screen real-estate when coding. However two 1920x1200 displays are enough for me and I suspect that a 1920x1080 and the old screen next to it will suffice for you. However this differs per person. I suggest borrowing a monitor from a friend and testing if it works for you.

Comment: This answered all of my concerns! Thanks for taking the time. I think I will go ahead and order the 27" 1920x1080. I believe it will be crisp enough for my development environment. After having two monitors at my internship, it's a necessity now.

Comment: Tell us how does it feel. I believe 1920×1080 is enough even for 27 inch.